# Add together an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to add together an array of objects, using reduce however i can't get it work.

```
const testArray = [ 
    {
        "T1": 1
    },
    {
        "T2": 12
    },
    {
        "T3": 20
    }
]
```

reduce function

```
const q = testArray.reduce((count, x) => count + x.P1Count);
```

outcome = 33

Comment: The objects in the array have different keys. Is there a possibility of having more than one keys?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the values and reduce the values as well.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    array = [{ "T1": 1 }, { "T2": 12 }, { "T3": 20 }],
    total = array.reduce(
        (s, o) => Object.values(o).reduce(add, s),
        0
    );

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument of the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function will be the member of the array the reduce is being called on. In your case, which will be `{ T[i]: ... }` where `i = 1, 2, 3`.

You can try this:

```js
const testArray = [ 
    {
        "T1": 1
    },
    {
        "T2": 12
    },
    {
        "T3": 20
    }
]
const x = testArray.reduce((count, x, index) => {
  const key = `T${index+1}`; // prepare the dynamic key T1, T2,...
  return count + x[key];
}, 0); // <-- 0 is the initial value of sum 

console.log(x)
```